# Error with simple Django custom filter

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I'm using this in my template:

```
{% load bb_tags %}
{{ op1 | encode_search_string: op2 }}
```

This is bb_tags.py:

```
import urllib
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='encode_search_string')
def encode_search_string(op1_name, op2_name):
    return urllib.quote_plus("{} vs {}".format(op1_name, op2_name))
```

I get this error:

```
encode_search_string requires 1 arguments, 0 provided
```

wtf? :(

Comment: Try removing space before `op2` in template and probably around `|` too for `op1`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was: removing the space!

```
{{ op1 | encode_search_string:op2 }}
```

Thanks a bunch, @Rohan!